# Rails app, foreign_key column unknown in MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mysql2

I have an extra MySQL database set up for legacy data migration in a Rails 3 app.  I can easily connect to it through this class:

```
class External < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :legacy
end
```

There are two models that inherit this class:

```
class LegacySize < External

  set_table_name 'size'
  set_primary_key 'size_id'
  belongs_to :product, :class_name => 'LegacyProduct', :foreign_key => 'product_id'

end

class LegacyProduct < External

  set_table_name 'product'
  set_primary_key 'product_id'
  has_many :sizes, :class_name => 'LegacySize'

end
```

Looks fine with a few simple ActiveRecord queries:

```
> ls = pp LegacySize.all
  LegacySize Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `size`.* FROM `size` 
[#<LegacySize size_id: 1, name: "small", product_id: 1>,
 #<LegacySize size_id: 2, name: "medium", product_id: 1>,
 #<LegacySize size_id: 3, name: "large", product_id: 1>]

> lp = pp LegacyProduct.all
  LegacyProduct Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `product`.* FROM `product` 
[#<LegacyProduct product_id: 1, name: "shirt", price: 10.0>]
```

But when I try to get to the associations, it looks for the column 'legacy_product_id' instead of 'product_id', which I am defining as the foreign key in the size model:

```
> lp = LegacyProduct.find(1).sizes
  LegacyProduct Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `product`.* FROM `product` WHERE `product`.`product_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  LegacySize Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `size`.* FROM `size` WHERE `size`.`legacy_product_id` = 1
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'size.legacy_product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `size`.* FROM `size`  WHERE `size`.`legacy_product_id` = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'size.legacy_product_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `size`.* FROM `size`  WHERE `size`.`legacy_product_id` = 1
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You did `reload!` the console after changing the model, we presume?  It looks correct as you have it.

Comment: yes, did `reload!` after every change

Comment: Try moving the `foreign_key` option from the `belongs_to` to the `has_many :sizes`. If that doesn't work, try putting the `foreign_key` on both sides of the association.

Comment: Thanks Zabba!  It works with `has_many :sizes, :class_name => 'LegacySize', :foreign_key => 'product_id'` in the `LegacyProduct` class.

Comment: @Zabba your "comment" worked fine for me too, could you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `foreign_key` option from the `belongs_to` to the `has_many :sizes`:

```
class LegacyProduct < External
    ...
    has_many :sizes, :class_name => 'LegacySize', :foreign_key => 'product_id'
    ...
```